# Create mutually exclusive form fields with Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular app where I would like to make two form fields mutually exclusive. As a result, when a use types into one text fields I would like the other to be cleared automatically.

A trivial example is as follows, a form with kilos and pound input fields:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    kilos: <input ng-model="kilos"><br/>
    pounds: <input ng-model="pounds"><br/>
</div>
```

Currently I use `$scope.$watch` to enforce the exclusivity rule:

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.kilos = '2';
        $scope.pounds = '';

        $scope.$watch("pounds", function() {
            $scope.kilos = "";     
        });

        $scope.$watch("kilos", function() {
            $scope.pounds = ""; 
        });  
    });
```

(You can see the code running in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8WV3u/2/))

However, when pounds is updated, it clears kilos, which in turn fires the other watch clearing pounds again. The net result is that the first keypress is swallowed!

How can I enforce this logic without this side effect?

I would like to be able to implement this without adding any further directive, e.g. `ng-change`, to the template. We have a separate team creating the UI, so would like to handle this logic entirely within the controller.

Comment: short of using events would probably have to write custom `ngModel` formatter in a directive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ek7xd/) which uses no additional directives per your request. The idea is to only change the inputs when necessary (i.e. when both have values). Relevant code is as follows:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.kilos = '2';
    $scope.pounds = '';

    $scope.notExclusive = function(){
        return $scope.kilos.length > 0 && $scope.pounds.length > 0;
    };

    $scope.$watch("pounds", function() {
        if($scope.notExclusive()){
            $scope.kilos = "";    
        }             
    });

    $scope.$watch("kilos", function() {
       if($scope.notExclusive()){
            $scope.pounds = "";    
        }     
    });  
});
```

Comment: That is so simple - why didn't I think of that?! Thank you!

Comment: You're quite welcome, ColinE. It's just fresh eyes, I'm sure. :)

Comment: Nicely done. It'd probably be worth writing a custom directive to allow for better handling across more fields.

Comment: Thank you, kindly. I've a hunch it could be handled without the watches using ng-change instead, but the specification was to go without an additional directive. What OP wants, OP gets. :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this (example)[http://plnkr.co/edit/MBViS59uaelyHcXJODKV]. Declare inputs, use `number` so angular handles it properly.

```
  <input type="number" ng-model="kilos" ng-change="ktolbs()">
  <br>
  <input type="number" ng-model="pounds" ng-change="lbstok()">
  <br>
```

Write some on change functions and let it roll.

```
  $scope.lbstok = function() {
    $scope.kilos = 2.2 * $scope.pounds;
  };

  $scope.ktolbs = function() {
    $scope.pounds = $scope.kilos / 2.2;
  }
```

This watch code will change one based on the other. Again using the `number` type for input helps a lot...

```
  $scope.$watch('kilos', function() {
    $scope.pounds = $scope.kilos / 2.2;
  });

  $scope.$watch('pounds', function() {
    $scope.kilos = $scope.pounds * 2.2;
  });
```

Comment: Thanks - but this doesn't make the two fields exclusive of each other. Perhaps I chose a bad example with kilos and pounds!